# OnFocus/OnBlur events not registered

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, onfocus

I feel really stupid asking for this, but remarkably I'm banging my head for an hour already. Here is the code:

```
<div id="img1" onfocus="alert('test');" onblur="alert('test');">
 <img id="image1" name="image1" src="image1.jpg"  alt="Pciture 1">&nbsp;
</div>
```

Both events (`Focus`/`Blur`) should call a function, but even this simple test (`alert`) doesn't work. Both of these tags are in the body section, tried changing the `DOCTYPE` definition - no effect.

W3 spew an error:

> there is no attribute "ONFOCUS"

My main goal is to use the events directly on the `img` tags, but for some reason that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<div>` and `<img>` don't normally have a focus or blur event, but you can try setting a tabindex on it as a workaround. It's a bit strange though.

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/blurfocus.html

Answer (score 8):

by default div is not an interactive element so it does not gain focus at all, try to add an `tabindex` attribute to div such as `tabindex="1"` then it will be focusable

Comment: Thanks its working fine, but i have to click on the element to make it work, it's not exactly what i wanted.

Comment: Then you may look for `mouseover` and `mouseout`, or `focusin` and `focusout` in IE

Answer (score 2):

> The onfocus event occurs when an
>   element receives focus either by the
>   pointing device or by tabbing
>   navigation. This attribute may be used
>   with the following elements: A, AREA,
>   LABEL, INPUT, SELECT, TEXTAREA, and
>   BUTTON.

**Source**: [w3c HTML4 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#events)

Neither a `div` nor an `img` can receive or lose focus, these are not interactive elements. You can enable them getting focus with setting `tabindex`.

> there are nodes which are not
>   focusable by default, like div, span,
>   table, etc, but can receive focus if
>   tabindex is applied

**Source**: http://nemisj.com/focusable/

Answer (score 0):

The W3C validator is correct, the div tag does not have onfocus or onblur as attributes.
See here:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_DIV.asp

Comment: Thanks it seems i forgot about the specifications

Comment: To the person who downvoted this, could you please tell me why?  To the best of my knowledge, my comment is true and correct and applies to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the events **`onmouseover`** and **`onmouseout`** are what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

You should not use inline JS for your event handlers. Use [unobtrusive javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Div Tag has no onfocus and onblur event. Please try mouseover ,mouseout etc..

Answer (score -1):

You can stop banging your head, first it hurts, secondly you can't ues onfocus or onblur on div elements.

Check da link:
[W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp)

What are you trying to achieve?